# Finding min() & second min() for each member

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a situation with the table data as in the picture, And I would like to select the min(code) and second_min(code) form each unique member.

[image]

i.e the desire output will look like

```
member  | min(code)     |  second_min(code)
-------------------------------------
1234    |       A       |       B
2345    |       A       |       C
3456    |       B       |       NULL
4567    |       A       |       NULL
6789    |       C       |       NULL
8765    |       NULL    |       NULL
```

Selecting the min() is straightforward & I have trouble in framing the SQL for finding second_min. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of how to find second `min` value from any table:

```
select min(value) 
from table
where value <> (
 select min(value) form table
);
```

You can add where conditions in the query as per the requirement. Please note that it may give you 0 if value doesn't exist, in this case, you can use `case` statement if you want to display different output.